# How to select particular text from webpage?

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to select some results which are given after pressing search button of webpage; those result are inside a `<span>` tag which has no id nor a class. How can I select this particular span?

```
Registration
ICANN Registrar:
MARKMONITOR INC.
Created:
1997-09-15
Expires:
2020-09-14
Updated:
2011-07-20
```

This is a sample code which I created through this I can search text from a webpage but I want to select particular span which shows the text`"Creation Date of a website"`

```cs
string downloadedString;
System.Net.WebClient client;

client = new System.Net.WebClient();
string text = "fun";
downloadedString = client.DownloadString("http://www.gmail.com");
if(downloadedString.Contains(text))
{
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

Comment: Use the HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: Almost duplicate of your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066542/how-to-select-particular-text-from-webpage-using-c-sharp), though it does appear this one is asked much more intelligently.

Comment: Please can u show me some code how to get HTMl Agility work i am not getting it to work...

Comment: @user2233501 a) SO is full of HAP answers. b) Without knowing your html, we can not post a real answer.

Comment: @user2233501 Did you even *try* to use it? It was less than an hour after SLaks suggested it that you said you can't get it to work. Google it, there are *countless* examples out there, but be warned, if <1 hour is the extent of your patience, you're going to have a tough time of it.

Comment: I also guess crawling all ICANN data is not so legal ...